# Creating clickable legends with D3

Tags: svg, d3.js, legend

I'm trying to create a multi-line chart with D3, but I'm stuck on toggling the visibility of lines off. So far, there is only one line, whilst I try to figure it all out (still a bit of a beginner with this), but I can't get the legend to appear, so I can't test if it'll actually get rid of the line too. Here is the JavaScript code:

```
var BlackBird = [{
    "population": "100",
    "year": "1970"
}, {
"population": "100.8",
    "year": "1971"
}, {
"population": "103.5",
    "year": "1972"
}, {
"population": "95.6",
    "year": "1973"
}, {
"population": "101.7",
    "year": "1974"
}, {
"population": "102",
    "year": "1975"
}
];

var vis = d3.select("#visualisation"),
    WIDTH = 1110,
    HEIGHT = 580,
    MARGINS = {
        top: 30,
        right: 20,
        bottom: 20,
        left: 50
    },

xScale = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([MARGINS.left, WIDTH - MARGINS.right])
    .domain([1970,2008]),

yScale = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([HEIGHT - MARGINS.top, MARGINS.bottom])
    .domain([0,300]),

xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(xScale)
    .ticks(25)
    .tickFormat(d3.format('0f')),

yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(yScale)
    .orient("left")
    .ticks(12);

vis.append("svg:g")
    .attr("class", "axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (HEIGHT - MARGINS.bottom) + ")")
    .call(xAxis);

vis.append("svg:g")
    .attr("class", "axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + (MARGINS.left) + ",0)")
    .call(yAxis);

var lineGen = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) {
        return xScale(d.year);
    })
    .y(function(d) {
        return yScale(d.population);
    })

    .interpolate("basis"); 

vis.append('path')
    .attr('d', lineGen(BlackBird))
    .attr('stroke-width', 5)
    .attr('fill', 'none')
    .attr('opacity', '0.2')
    .attr("id", "aline");

vis.append("text")
    .attr("x", WIDTH + MARGINS.left +10)             
    .attr("y", 10)    
    .attr("class", "legend")
    .style("fill", "steelblue")         
    .on("click", function(){
        var active   = aline.active ? false : true,
        newOpacity = active ? 0 : 1;
        d3.select("#aline").attr("opacity", newOpacity);
        aline.active = active;
    })
    .text("Blue Line");
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <html lang= "en"> <head> <meta charset="UTF-8"> <title>D3 Birds</title> <link rel="stylesheet" href="D3Bird2.css"> </head> <body> <svg id="visualisation" width="1140" height="600"></svg> <div id ="BlaBird"> <img src="Blackbird.png" alt="A Blackbird" class= "Birdie"> </div> <script src="d3.min.js" charset="utf-8"> </script> <script src="script2.js" charset="utf-8"></script> </body> </html>
```

CSS:

```
.axis path {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #777;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
.axis text {
  font-family: Lato;
  font-size: 13px;
}
#aline {
  stroke: #000;
  opacity: 0.5;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
#aline: hover {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
.Birdie {
  transition: 0.5s;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
#BlaBird {
  position: absolute;
  left: 1150px;
  top: 30px;
}
.legend {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-anchor: start;
}
```

Comment: Have you seen NVD3? It already has [something for this](http://nvd3.org/examples/line.html).

Comment: You have some incorrectly named variables in your legend.  svg = vis?  width = WIDTH?  margin = MARGINS?

Comment: Ah! I had not spotted the incorrect spellings! Thanks! :)
Although, the problem is not solved! D: Looked at a few examples, just can't seem to get it to work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you didn't include your HTML markup, but I'm assuming `#visualisation` is an SVG element.  Make sure you've assigned it height and width attributes.

Second, you don't assign a `stroke` color to your line.  I'm assuming you do this in CSS somewhere.

Third, after fixing your variable names, this line:

```
.attr("x", width + margin.left +10)
```

is the problem.  This pushes the text element outside of it's SVG.

Here's an [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/QZtQljxu8pQAw891BKDB?p=preview) where I've fixed some of this up.

**EDITS**

New problem after looking at your CSS.  You are setting the **attribute** opacity in code, the CSS sets the **style** opacity.  When both are set the browser will use the style.  So change your click handler to:

```
  .on("click", function() {
    var active = aline.active ? false : true,
      newOpacity = active ? 0 : 1;
    d3.select("#aline").style("opacity", newOpacity); //<-- set style, not attr
    aline.active = active;
  })
```

Example [updated](http://plnkr.co/edit/QZtQljxu8pQAw891BKDB?p=preview).

Comment: That seems 100% the answer! :D I can see it works as well, although, it still doesn't want to work on mine! x.x I'll add the other bits of code too, just in case there's a mistake someplace: (coming up in next comments!)

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang= "en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>D3 Birds</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="D3Bird2.css">
</head>
<body>
   <svg id="visualisation" width="1140" height="600"></svg>

       <div id ="BlaBird"> <img src="Blackbird.png" alt="A Blackbird" class= "Birdie">  </div>
 

    <script src="d3.min.js" charset="utf-8"> </script>
      <script src="script2.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</body>
</html>

Comment: .axis path {
    fill: none;
    stroke: #777;
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

    .axis text {
    font-family: Lato;
    font-size: 13px;
}


#aline {
stroke: #000;
opacity: 0.5;
 transition: 0.5s;
}

#aline:hover {
opacity: 1;
 transition: 0.5s;
}

.Birdie{
 transition: 0.5s;
 opacity: 0.5;
}


#BlaBird {
    position: absolute;
    left: 1150px;
    top: 30px;
}

.legend {
        font-size: 16px;         
        font-weight: bold;         
        text-anchor: start;
        } (Meant to add as well the first reply is in HTML, and this one is CSS! :) )

Comment: @dogtorwho, see updated answer.  Also, next time update your question with new code, don't cut/paste into a comment.  I took the liberty of updating your question this time.

Comment: WOO! Success! :D It's working now! Thank you /so/, so much for the help! You are brilliant! :)

Comment: Ahh, and apologises! :) Still a little new to all this, so just trying to get the hang of it all!